# CRTP: Call derived class templated method from base

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

please help me with the following problem:

I have a class declared as:

```
template<typename GEAR_TYPE>
class Rim
    :   /* Derive from GenericComponent Design perspective using CRTP */
        public Design::GenericComponent<Rim<GEAR_TYPE>>
{
public:
    template<typename IDENTIFICATION_TAG>
    typename Base::Parameter<typename IDENTIFICATION_TAG::UnitType, typename IDENTIFICATION_TAG::DataType>::QuantityType & DummyEquation( void )
    {
        return( Base::Parameter<typename IDENTIFICATION_TAG::UnitType, typename IDENTIFICATION_TAG::DataType>::QuantityType::from_value( 222 ) );
    }
};
```

which inherits from `Design::GenericComponent<>` using CRTP. Within Design::GenericComponent<> there is a method:

```
template<typename DERIVED_COMPONENT_TYPE>
class GenericComponent
{
public:
    template<typename PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>
    std::shared_ptr<Base::Parameter<typename PARAM_IDENTIFICATION::UnitType, typename PARAM_IDENTIFICATION::DataType>> get( void ) const
    {
        mParameters.template create<PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>( static_cast<const DERIVED_COMPONENT_TYPE *>( (this) )->template DummyEquation<PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>() );
    }
};
```

The `get()` method from `GenericComponent` should call the `DummyEquation()` templated method from the derived `Rim<GEAR_TYPE>` class. But the way it is implemented as listed does not work - compiler reports troubles with constness of this pointer when trying to cast to derived class...

How to get this working? I have tried almost every possible const qualifier placements but nothing solved my problem. Just one more thing to mention - the method `create<>()` cannot be qualified as `const` ( `create<>() const` ) as it modifies the content of it's owner class...

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me... Cheers Martin

Comment: DummyEquation needs to be a const method if you want to call it through a const pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to a `const` object (in the scope of `get`). Casting it down the inheritance hierarchy doesn't change the `const`-ness of the resulting object.

So either `DummyEquation` & `create` need to be `const` member functions, or `get` needs to be non-`const`.

Comment: So do I understand it right, the const at the end of method declaration specifies the constness of 'this' in scope of the method itself?